# How to change icon in runtime

Tags: vb.net

Nothing I have tried yet will work...
Everything I have tried, I looked over the internet, but nothing.
I download it then convert it to a .ico because there is no hosting provider on earth that lets me upload RAW .ico's and get them from the site.
I wan't the icon to be editable.

This is my code

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim logDirectoryProperties As System.IO.DirectoryInfo
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("C:/fileexplorer") Then
            Form1.Show()
        Else
            logDirectoryProperties = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectoryInfo("C:/fileexplorer")
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory("C:/fileexplorer")
            Dim path As String = "C:/fileexplorer/lastactivity.log"
            Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(path)
            Dim info As Byte() = New UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes("")
            fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length)
            fs.Close()
            My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/cornmanthe3rd/plex/512/System-explorer-icon.png", "C:/fileexplorer/logo.png")
            Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile("C:/fileexplorer/logo.png")
            img.Save("C:/fileexplorer/logo_dont_edit.ico", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Icon)
            Form1.Show()
        End If
        Me.Icon = New Icon("C:/fileexplorer/logo_dont_edit.ico")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: have you used the debugger to step thru that code and *see* what happens?

Comment: Yes, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.WebClient(v=vs.110).aspx) class's `DownloadFileAsync` method.

```
Dim wc As New WebClient
AddHandler wc.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf FileDownloaded
wc.DownloadFileAsync(Uri, filename)


Private Sub FileDownloaded(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
 'now assign image here as it has completed it's download
End Sub
```